# GNUplot use GN variable in a label

Tags: gnuplot

GN produces the variable STATS_max_y when plotting data.

I'd like to use it in a label, such as:

```
set label 4 "The highest value is: STATS_max_y"
```

but I can't see how to concatenate the GN variable and the label text.

I tried:

```
"The highest value is: . STATS_max_y"
```

and I get internal error : STRING operator applied to non-STRING type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
set label 4 sprintf("The highest value is: %f", a)
```

should do it. For more information, check out www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-464

Answer (score 0):

[edited]

"The highest value is: " . STATS_max_y - my suggestion

"The highest value is: . STATS_max_y"  - OPs code

So the closing quote is at a different position. The first line is a constant string ("...") concatenated (via the .-operator) with the variable <STATS_max_y>, the second line ist only a constant string (everything between the two quotes).

Comment: This is a code only answer.. . Can you elaborate how this is different from the OP's code?

I think you deleted the space between ```.``` and ```.STATS_max_y```.

Comment: Good idea but, unfortunately, yet it doesn't work because `STATS_max_y` is not a string. To make it work you should convert into string the numeric variable, something like `"The highest value is: ".sprintf("%f",STATS_max_y)` or in one step `sprintf("The highest value is: %f", STATS_max_y)`

Comment: @Hastur: you are right. It would work without (extra) conversion, if STATS_max_y was an integer number (then the conversion to string would be made 'internally' by gnuplot), but as it is a real number, sprintf or something like that is necessary.